# jQuery .load returning empty div (PHP page)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a PHP control panel I'm currently working on.  I need a div in one of my PHP files to automatically refresh and I came across an jQuery solution which can automatically reload certain parts of a website.  The problem is every time I include the script, when the setInterval runs it just turns the div into a blank element instead of loading the content.

My site works by having a master PHP called "panel.php" which loads various HTML documents (.php files) using "include".  One of those HTML documents is called "printers.php".

Inside printers.php I want to reload this div:

```
<div id="tsd"><?php echo time(); ?></div>
```

So at the top of my code in the head tag of "printers.php" I added this code:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
    setInterval(function () {
        $( "#tsd" ).load("panel.php #tsd");
    }, 2000);
</script>
```

Now when the panel.php document loads, the timestamp shows for 2 seconds, then disappears and the div element just goes blank with no data in it.  I can't figure out why it is reloading a blank div? Any ideas would help.

Comment: done any basic debugging, like checking what happens when you manually hit `panel.php` yourself every 2 seconds?

Comment: ur making the scripts run just for 2 seconds with setinterval

Comment: Thanks for your responses.  Sorry I'm not familiar with AJAX and was under the impression it was, looks like it's just standard jQuery.  However, the point is it should reload the timestamp after every 2 seconds.  I haven't put my real code in the div yet (just a timestamp for now) as I can't even get the timestamp to refresh.  My goal is to refresh the content every 2 seconds.

Comment: Can you show us what's in `panel.php`? I've tried this on my machine and it works okay, leading me to believe something inside `panel.php` is causing it to break. For example, it may hit a php error before it gets to `#tsd` therefore not creating the div in the response, meaning the `load` method cant find the div to load into the `#tsd` in `printers.php`.

Comment: Why $("#tsd").load("panel.php #tsd"); And not $("#tsd").load("panel.php");

Comment: I only wish to reload the content inside a particular div instead of the entire page, if that makes sense.  The way I understood it is I have to put the #tsd in again.  Am I wrong?

Comment: @MarcosSedrez - the `load` method can get specific fragments from the loaded page via a jQuery selector [(docs)](http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments). So if you wanted to load into your page a div from `test.php` that has id `#c` it would be `.load("test.php #c");`

Comment: @ImClarky sure you can download them here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/88d65050b73480699a88576af349bd1e#file-panel-php and https://gist.github.com/anonymous/139b8058fe3674a9cbbdc659bad8f4aa#file-printers-php

Comment: You don't have a  'tsd' id in your panel.php.

Comment: @MarcoSedrez, once again thank you for your response.  The panel.php includes the printers.php which has the tsd id.  So the user is always running panel.php and it will always have "tsd" in the final outputted HTML code (taken from loading printers.php) if that makes sense.  The reason I know the code works is because when I load the page I see the timestamp in the div show up perfectly normal, however after 2 seconds have elapsed and the setInterval runs, the div just goes empty and disappears.

Comment: If I've understood your `panel.php` code correctly, try `$('#tsd').load('panel.php?page=printers #tsd');` If that works, let me know and i'll write up the reasoning behind it in an answer. (Don't think I can fit it in a comment)

Comment: @ImClarky, you sir are a genius! Thank you so much, I spent the whole day pondering about this one.  You have fixed the issue, works a treat now! Please post this as a proper reply so I can accept your solution.  Moral of the story = you need to include get parameters in a .load request too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add the `GET` parameters. Change your Interval script from:

```
$( "#tsd" ).load("panel.php #tsd");
```

to

```
$('#tsd').load('panel.php?page=printers #tsd');
```

---

Upon inspection of your `panel.php` code, I noticed this `if` statement:

```
if (!isset($_GET['page'])) 
    header('location: panel.php?page=dashboard');
else 
    include('restricted/sitepages/'.$_GET['page'].'.php');
```

Thereby, because you were omitting the `GET` parameter `page` it was loading the *Dashboard* page instead of the *Printers* page; and I'm guessing the *Dashboard* page does not have a div with the id `tsd`. Therefore it was loading nothing because `#tsd` does not exist in the loaded response.

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate your help.  It's nice to have someone else look at your code once in while.  You tend to get tunnel vision when your working on something for a long time.

Comment: @user1928362 - no problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Place the html code in the panel.php and make a recursion there.
So that panel.php looks like this

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready( function(){

        refreshClock();
});
    function refreshClock(){
    $('#tsd').load('printers.php', function(){
       setTimeout(refreshClock, 2000);
    });
}
</script>

<div id="tsd"></div>
```

Comment: The setInterval() method calls a function or evaluates an expression at specified intervals (in milliseconds).

Comment: Thank you for your response, I tried this but unfortunately it does not work.  I believe it doesn't work because as Marcos described the setTimeout does not refresh the content after every X seconds like I need.  I tried changing it to setInterval but still get the same issue.